# Can't make my code identify specific strings

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm coding for a little school project. I wanna read a .txt file and find what's between "pergunta[]" and a question mark but can't manage to make my program give me that.

I have already tried what someone suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55188056/how-to-extract-text-between-the-matching-pattern-in-python?noredirect=1&lq=1) but it doesn't seem to work for me, as it does not retrieve the piece of string I want and apparently does not even enter the if statement.

("perguntas" means questions)

```py
import pyttsx3

speak = pyttsx3.init()

running = True
perguntas = open(r"C:\Users\jeana\Desktop\perguntas.txt", "r")
texto = perguntas.read()

while running:
    if "pergunta5 " in texto:
        data = texto.split("pergunta5 ")[1].split("?")[0]
        print(data) #tried adding this line but it is never printed
        speak.say(data)
        speak.runAndWait()
        running = False
    print("um loop") #I added this just to know the code reaches this point
    running = False
```

I expected my code to find the question that is between "pergunta[]"(5 in this case, just to simplify) and "?" and text-to-speech it, but for some reason this code simply outputs something that sounds like a "p" and no error messages. I wonder if I'm missing something that is fundamental here...

The text file looks like this:

```
pergunta1 Quanto é dois mais dois? R: 4 - 2
pergunta2 Quanto é cinco menos 2? R: 3 - 2
pergunta3 Quanto é cinco menos 1? R: 4 - 2
pergunta4 A peppa pig é um? R: Porco - 3
pergunta5 Qual a cor do cavalo branco do napoleão? R: Branco - 3
```

edit:
A simpler version of my code is

```py
text = "a lot of text with some question1 yadayadayada? question2 dayadayadaya?"
if "question1" in text:
    data = text.split("question1")[1].split("?")[0]
    print(data)
```

and the output should go:

```
yadayadayada
```

Comment: Try `print`ing `data` before the `speak` statement to debug the issue.

Comment: Why don’t you print the value of “data” as well to help you debugging. Oh that’s just what @Selcuk suggested too.

Comment: Are you sure `speak.say()` can handle accented characters?

Comment: There are a few different places a bug could occur between reading the file, selecting the text, and speaking the text. It would help if you made a [mre].

Comment: I am sure speak.say() can handle UTF-8 characters @JohnGordon

Comment: If the `print()` statement never shows up, then either your data file is not as shown, or something else is going on.  How are you running the code?  Do you just type `python myscript.py` at the command line, or do you run from an IDE, or some other way?

Comment: If I run your code, but remove the `speak`-related stuff, it runs just fine and prints question 5. The issue appears to be with the text-to-speech library you're using. Alternatively, your text file may have some encoding or other issue that we're not privy to (I just pasted the content you provided here into a text file and ran with that an it was fine).

Comment: Is there a reason you have everything in a `while` loop? This effectively does nothing, since every code path ends with `running = False`, so why did you put that in?

Comment: I created the .txt file using windows noteblock. I am just guessing it didn't add any special encoding?

Comment: About running it on ```while```, it's because this is gonna be a working TTS that will run over and over asking several questions to some kids who don't know how to read yet. No practical use in this specific piece of code

Comment: Since you said in [your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57549956/4518341) it was an encoding problem, not a problem with your code per se, I'm voting to close the question as "can no longer be reproduced".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out @JohnGordon made me see what was wrong. The code itself has no problems, but the .txt file has some more encoding to it. All I did was to simply paste all the text into a string inside the code and it worked just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Use built-in the method "with" to read the file, a regular expression is to use to split statement, 'pergunta.' here "." means anything. Refer regex for python for more clarification.

```
import re
with open('perguntas.txt','r') as f:
     content = f.read()

sp = re.split('pergunta.', content)
print(sp)
```

Comment: This doesn't explain why the current code is not working, which is the real question.